# Set Working Hours in Microsoft Project

Tags: microsoft-project

How to set working hours of (8:00 AM - 6:00 PM) in Microsoft Project 2019?

I already try through, Project > Change Working Time > Work Weeks > Details.
But it didn't calculated my duration correctly.

Comment: How did you attempt to enter your duration? See the answer here: https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11224/changing-default-working-hours-from-8-hr-day-to-4-hr-day-in-microsoft-project-20 Also, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-the-general-working-days-and-times-for-a-project-c4587751-2b88-449d-87e5-d3312d16771d